# Display NULL if some value is not found from WHERE CLAUSE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to JOIN two tables based on their columns and a WHERE IN Clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.document_num, t2.file_name 
FROM 
    infocard_1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN 
    web_pub_subfile AS t2 on t1.info_card_id = t2.info_card_id
WHERE 
    lower(t1.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%' AND 
    t2.file_name = 
       CASE 
          WHEN t2.file_name IN ('00350.dwg', '00924.dwg', '00960.dwg', '00973.dwg') 
             THEN t2.file_name
             ELSE NULL
       END
```

I am getting output in this format

```
document_num    file_name
-------------------------
SU-SH3A081      00960.DWG
SU-SH3A148      00973.DWG
```

But I would like to get

```
document_num    file_name
-------------------------
null            00350.dwg
null            00924.dwg
SU-SH3A081      00960.DWG
SU-SH3A148      00973.DWG
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: Try `FROM web_pub_subfile AS t1 LEFT JOIN infocard_1 AS t2`

Comment: Even if you have got your answer, you must study about joins in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct t1.document_num,t2.file_name 
FROM web_pub_subfile AS t2  
LEFT JOIN infocard_1 AS t1 on t1.info_card_id = t2.info_card_id AND 
                              lower(t1.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%'
WHERE  t2.file_name IN ('00350.dwg','00924.dwg','00960.dwg','00973.dwg')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. Read more about the types of `JOINS` [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `CASE` expression in `WHERE`? This makes it very hard to read. Use `AND`or `OR` and parentheses when necessary to build your `WHERE` clause. Your clause simply translates to:

```
WHERE lower(t1.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%' 
AND t2.file_name IN ('00350.dwg','00924.dwg','00960.dwg','00973.dwg')
```

To get records from a table even when they don't have a match in the other table, you'd outer join the other table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic.document_num, wps.file_name 
FROM web_pub_subfile wps
LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic ON ic.info_card_id = wps.info_card_id
                        AND lower(ic.vault_name) LIKE N'%su-spec-release%'
WHERE wps.file_name IN ('00350.dwg','00924.dwg','00960.dwg','00973.dwg');
```

I replaced your alias names with something readable.

Comment: Well, seems I was a bit slow :-)

Comment: No probs bro. Many thanks for your heads up... I'll take your suggestion on ALIASES

Comment: Any idea why am I getting duplicates?